# Переход по страницам в Ionic-приложении (Routing)

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ionic

Не работает переход по страницам в приложении на Ionic. В папку view положил файл qwe.html со следующим содержанием: `qweqwe` В app.js написал вот это

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('index',{
            url:'/',
            abstract:true,
            templateUrl:'index.html'
        })
        .state('index.qwe',{
            url:'/view/qwe',
            views:{
                'qwe':{
                    templateUrl:'view/qwe.html'
                }
            }
        });
})
```

В index.html написано вот это:

```
<body ng-controller="main">
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <a href="#/">index</a>
      <a href="#/view/qwe">qwe</a>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </ion-content>

    <div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced">
    </div>
  </ion-pane>
</body>
```

Кажется, всё сделано как в многочисленных документациях по Ionic и Angular, но при клике по ссылкам на экране ничего не меняется. Изменяется только адресная строка. В консоли на вкладке Network показано, что файл qwe.html найден. Пробовал добавлять в объявление модели 'ngRoute' и подключать angular-route.js - исход один и тот же. Что может быть не так?

Comment: какой именно роутер используется? если встроенный ангуляровский - откуда взялись стейты? если ui-router - откуда директивы `ng-view`?

Comment: я только вчера сел за айоник и ангуляр и многого не понимаю. мысли путаются не только в голове но и в коде, поэтому если Вы точно знаете где моя ошибка, пожалуйста объясните. Я практически не имею понятия почему написал там именно это)

Comment: замени ng-view на ui-view. И вместо того чтобы бездумно откуда-то все копировать, стоит хотя бы пример посмотреть на том же ionic

Comment: заменил и мало что изменилось. я бы даже сказал ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заработало когда написал в app.js состояния вот в таком виде

```
.state('qwe',{
     url:'/qwe',
     templateUrl:'view/qwe.html'
})
```

В index.html написал директиву `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>`